# How can I create an array of duplicate case-insensitive strings from another array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string, duplicates

I have an array of strings.  I'm wanting to change the name of these duplicate strings to append a numerical value to make them unique like so...

**Original Array**

```
a, a, A, b, c, D, d
```

**Corrected Array**

```
a, a1, A2, b, c, D, d1
```

I've gotten close to this with the following code; however, if the strings are a different case structure then they aren't currently considered duplicates with this code snippet.  I would like them to be considered duplicates, but yet not change their case in the results array.

```
duplicate_counter = 1
duplicates = Array.new
duplicates = file_columns.select{ |e| file_columns.count(e) > 1 } # get duplicate column names

duplicates.each{ |x| file_columns.delete(x) }
duplicates.sort!
duplicates.each_with_index do |d, i|

  if i > 0
     if d == duplicates[i-1]
        d = d.strip + duplicate_count.to_s
        duplicate_count += 1
     else 
        duplicate_count = 1
     end
  end

  # Add back the column names, but with the appended numerical counts to make them unique
  file_columns.push(d)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are over thinking it considerably. I'm sure there are better ways to do this as well, but it gets the job done.

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'A', 'b', 'c', 'D', 'd']
letters = Hash.new(-1)
a.map do |letter|
  l = letter.downcase
  letters[l] += 1
  if (letters[l] > 0)
    "#{letter}#{letters[l]}"
  else
    "#{letter}"
  end
end
```

Comment: sweet works perfectly! and yes over thinking it! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it if letters independent of case are not necessarily grouped. For example, it will convert this array:

```
arr = %w{ a D a A b c D a d }
  #=> ["a", "D", "a", "A", "b", "c", "D", "a", "d"]
```

to:

```
["a", "D", "a1", "A2", "b", "c", "D1", "a3", "d2"]
```

**Code**

```
def convert(arr)
  arr.each_with_index
     .group_by { |c,_| c.downcase }
     .values
     .flat_map { |c|
       c.map
        .with_index { |(f,l),i| [i > 0 ? f<<i.to_s : f, l] } }
     .sort_by(&:last)
     .map(&:first)
end
```

**Example**

For `arr` above:

```
convert(arr)
 #=> ["a", "D", "a1", "A2", "b", "c", "D1", "a3", "d2"]
```

**Explanation**

Dear reader, if you are new to Ruby, this may look impossibly complex. If you break it down into steps, however, it's not that bad. After you gain experience and become familiar with commonly-used methods, it will come quite naturally. Here I've used the following methods, chained together so that the return value of each becomes the receiver of the next:

- [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)
- [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)
- [Hash#values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-values)
- [Enumerable#flat_map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map)
- [Enumerable#sort_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)
- [Enumerable#first](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-first)

Here's what's happening.

```
enum = arr.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["a", "D", "a", "A", "b", "c",
  #                  "D", "a", "d"]:each_with_index>
h = enum.group_by { |c,_| c.downcase }
  #=> {"a"=>[["a", 0], ["a", 2], ["A", 3], ["a", 7]],
  #    "d"=>[["D", 1], ["D", 6], ["d", 8]],
  #    "b"=>[["b", 4]],
  #    "c"=>[["c", 5]]}
a = h.values
  #=> [[["a", 0], ["a", 2], ["A", 3], ["a", 7]],
  #    [["D", 1], ["D", 6], ["d", 8]],
  #    [["b", 4]],
  #    [["c", 5]]]
b = a.flat_map { |c| c.map.with_index { |(f,l),i| [i > 0 ? f<<i.to_s : f, l] } }
  #=> [["a", 0], ["a1", 2], ["A2", 3], ["a3", 7], ["D", 1],
  #    ["D1", 6], ["d2", 8], ["b", 4], ["c", 5]]
c = b.sort_by(&:last)
  #=> [["a", 0], ["D", 1], ["a1", 2], ["A2", 3], ["b", 4],
  #    ["c", 5], ["D1", 6], ["a3", 7], ["d2", 8]]
c.map(&:first)
  #=> ["a", "D", "a1", "A2", "b", "c", "D1", "a3", "d2"]
```